# jquery doesn't work with rails and foundation 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've added Foundation 4 to an existing Rails app using the directions on the Foundation Rails page.

The problem I'm having is that my custom jQuery code doesn't work with Foundation. Here is the only line of javascript code in the head section of application.html.haml:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

Here is the application.js file:

```
//= require vendor/custom.modernizr
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require datepickers
//= require table_accordions
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require form_validators
//= require text_area_maxlength
//= require s3_upload
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

I've fiddled around with multiple sequences of these and looked at countless pages on the net in the last couple days without finding a clue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have additional code in the application.js you need to add:

```
//= require_self
```

Comment: Thanks, but the listing above is the entire file. I tried adding it anyway; no change.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the require_self to the file so that the 1 line of additional js in it $(document).foundtation(); will be included.

Comment: I wish I could select your answer as correct. :D I had something very similar (I just had fewer requires in my application.js. The funny thing is that it worked fine without require_self in the beginning. That is until I added compass to the mix. After that I started getting the funky "TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function - $(document).foundation();" error. This helped a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I removed

`$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });`

from **application.js** and manually added

`<script>$(document).foundation().foundation('joyride', 'start');</script>`

right above the closing body tag in **application.html.erb** file and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.

It turns out that when I updated the bundle in my app, jquery-rails updated to jquery 1.9.1, which is incompatible with most of my custom javascripts.

I changed my jquery version back to 1.8.3, and everything works again. And the site is significantly improved with Foundation.